# Epson TM-T88V slow with JavaPOS

Tags: printing, epson, javapos

I'm using Epson JavaPOS to print a receipt with Epson TM-T88V ethernet version.
Also printing some stupid data with prt.printNormal() the print is very very slow both on Windows 7 and Windows Xp.
Instead printing the test page using Windows driver, the print is very fast!!

Maybe is a limit of JavaPOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by myself.
The problem was due to the fact that you need to use transaction to use the full speed of the printer.
So something like this:

```
printer.transactionPrint(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, POSPrinterConst.PTR_TP_TRANSACTION);
```

and

```
printer.transactionPrint(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, POSPrinterConst.PTR_TP_NORMAL);
```

This solves the problem permanently.